# How did Magento know language was installed?

Tags: magento2, language

I just installed this language pack:

http://imaginaerum.github.io/magento2-language-fr-fr/en.html#section-installation

The way I installed it was like this:
1. create folder via ftp in app/i18n/imaginaerum/fr_fr/  unzip file here
2. create store view and change language to french (france).I used language code "fr"

it works.

I'm curious how Magento knew to use that folder as a language pack. It seems to me I did nothing to really connect the language choice with that pack. And while it is doing exactly what I want I don't know how/why so I am kind of curious as I am just starting to learn how magento works.

Comment: for all languge there is specific code. for example : fr_fr and you select french from admin. so magento will check if languge pack is available it will use it or use magento default text

Comment: @Kul How did Magento know to look in that folder for the code though? Is there a specific folder that magento looks for language packs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into `app/i18n/Magento` you can find different language packages. Every package to be recognized by Magento must have `registration.php` file.

We have 2 cases to read this file.

**1. Install via composer.**

To be executed this file must be added to `composer.json` in the package directory.

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ]
}
```

**2. Not installed via composer**

Magento looks for this file in predefined dirs.

See

```
app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php
```

line

```
$pathList[] = dirname(__DIR__) . '/i18n/*/*/registration.php';
```

That's it.

Same mechanism exists for modules and themes which allows to be placed either under `app` or `vendor` folders.